# Call overridden method of parent class with child class object in python

Tags: python

I have came around this question during an interview:

```
class Parent(object):
    def A(self):
        print "in A"
class Child(Parent):
    def A(self):
       print "in B"

C=Child()
```

Question come here:

> is there any way i can call Parent class function `A` with child object only at instance level without doing any changes in classes?

have searched many question but didn't find any satisfactory answer.Please reply.

Thanks.

Comment: No it will call Parent class method A not of B as it is overridden.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) builtin.

```
>>> super(Child, C).A()
in A
```

It is usually used to call super class implementation inside subclasses, but it is also allowed outside. Docs state:

> Also note that super() is not limited to use inside methods. The two
>   argument form specifies the arguments exactly and makes the
>   appropriate references.

Comment: Or `super(C.__class__,C).A()` without needing the class name hardcoded

Answer (score 3):

Call the method on the class explicitly.

```
Parent.A(C)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you see, methods of objects always have the `self` parameter.

You can call objects methods as

```
C.A()
```

or equivalently, by explicitly passing the `self` parameter, as:

```
Child.A(C)
```

In the second way, you can call also the method of the parent class using the `C` instance:

```
Parent.A(C)
```

If you are looking for a general method to solve this (i.e. without knowing the name of the parent class), you can use [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) and [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type):

```
super(type(C)).A(C)
```

However, `super()` has a nice additional argument to specify an object instance, so you could write also:

```
super(type(C), C).A()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `super` call passing the `type` of child class and the desired instance object which is just `C`:

```
super(type(C), C).A() # of the form super(class, obj) where class == Child and obj == C
```

Answer (score -1):

Having instance `C` we could get its base class and call its `A()`:
`C.__class__.__base__().A()`