# Ways to resolve overriding?

Tags: python, overriding

If we inherit a class and if overriding of methods occurs, in c++ scope resolution operator is used to resolve that problem. Is there any way in python??? Here is an eg code :

```
class a:
    def c(self):
        print('base class')
class b(a):
    def c(self):
        print('derived class')
d=b()
d.c()
```

Here I am trying to access the method c of the base class using the object d. How it can be done???

Comment: I don't know what you means but if you want to execute `a.c()` in `b.c()` then use `super().c()`

Comment: Can you update the question to include an example for what you're trying to do? is [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) what you're looking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call overridden method of parent class with child class object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821455/call-overridden-method-of-parent-class-with-child-class-object-in-python)

Comment: If you need this, it might hint at a code smell and show that you have violated the Liskov substitution principle in your class design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Here is the code:

```
class a:
    def c(self):
        print('base class')
class b(a):
    def c(self):
        print('derived class')

d=b()
super(b, d).c() # <<--- inline access to super(base) c method
```

if you looking for a better approach, you can add this method to the child class, like this:

```
class a:
    def c(self):
        print('base class')
class b(a):
    def c(self):
        print('derived class')
    def c_base(self): # <-- built in access to super(base) c method
        super().c()

d=b()
b.c_base() # <<--- call the method
```

### Update:

You can access to base's methods via its name by send an instance of class or its child class to that method:

```
Parrent.OverriddenMethod(object_of_child)
```

In your example:

```
a.c(d)
```